# ¿Cómo enviar un correo desde un formulario PHP a dos cuentas diferentes de correo electrónico?

Tags: php, email, html-correo

mi duda es como puedo agregar una nueva dirección de correo electrónico para que lleguen los correos desde mi formulario PHP, con una cuenta me funciona perfecto, pero al querer agregar otra dirección dudo mucho como hacerlo, espero me puedan auxiliar, este es mi código PHP:

```
<?php
/*He intendado agregarla de esta forma, sin embargo me sale error en la "," ya que al parecer no es su sintaxis*/
$destino = "cuenta1@gmail.com", "cuenta2@yahoo.com";

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["correo];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre .
             "\n\nCorreo: " . $email . 
             "\n\nMensaje: " ."\n". $mensaje;

$enviado = mail($destino,$asunto,$contenido);

if ($enviado)
header("Location:contacto.html");
else
header("Location:error.html");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que esta concatenación es incorrecta:

```
$destino = "cuenta1@gmail.com", "cuenta2@yahoo.com";
```

**Falta una coma entre las direcciones**. Puedes ponerlo así:

```
$destino = "cuenta1@gmail.com, ", "cuenta2@yahoo.com";
                            #^Coma aquí para separar destinatarios
```

O bien así:

```
$destino = "cuenta1@gmail.com, cuenta2@yahoo.com";
```

Te señalo que mandar direcciones concatenadas a diversos destinatarios es por lo general una mala práctica, porque todos ven las direcciones de los otros. Esto sería factible en un tipo de correo familiar por ejemplo, o de compañeros de una clase. Pero en el ámbito profesional, deberías enviar las direcciones como `Bcc`, así, nadie ve las direcciones de los otros.

En el Manual de PHP tienes ejemplos sobre cómo mandar copias ocultas, las cuales deben ponerse en la cabecera, aquí un ejemplo:

```
#Ponemos las direcciones en un array para simplificar luego con implode
$destino = array("cuenta1@gmail.com", "cuenta2@yahoo.com");

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["correo];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre .
             "\n\nCorreo: " . $email . 
             "\n\nMensaje: " ."\n". $mensaje;

$cabeceras  = "From: Tu Nombre <tu-email@tu-dominio.com>" . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Reply-To: tu-email@tu-dominio.com" . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(). "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "BCC: ". implode(",", $destino) . "\r\n";


$enviado = mail(null,$asunto,$contenido,$cabeceras);

if ($enviado)
  header("Location:contacto.html");
else
  header("Location:error.html");
```

Aquí se manda todo en las cabeceras: la lista de copias ocultas, el título, a quién se debe responder, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia que era una mala práctica, pero entonces para que las direcciones se envíen como `Bcc` cómo lo puedo añadir a mi código?

Comment: @MayraXimenaVargas revisa la respuesta editada. He puesto todo en cabeceras, en ese caso se pone `null` en el primer parámetro de `mail` porque en las cabeceras se configura todo el correo.

Comment: he intentado realizarlo de esa manera, sin embargo no llegan los correos a las cuentas que me gustaría que llegaran :(

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a alguno de los correos que hay en `$destino`? Revisa en la carpeta SPAM a ver si están ahí los mensajes. Y, ¿en qué Location entra el código, en el de ` contacto.html` o en el de `error.html`? @MayraXimenaVargas

Comment: @MayraXimenaVargas faltaba el salto de línea aquí: `$cabeceras .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(). "\r\n";` corrige eso y prueba, debería funcionar. Si no funciona, en vez del `null` puedes poner tu dirección de correo electrónico, así recibirías tú una copia y los otros destinatarios copias ocultas: `$enviado = mail("tu-email@tu-dominio.com",$asunto,$contenido,$cabeceras);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto era el salto de línea. Me has ayudado bastante, muchísimas gracias ^_^